# Australian re-entering South Africa on 90 day visa

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, south-africa, repeat-visits

The South African High Commission in Australia is unable to tell me the period required, after completing a 90-day visa in South Africa, before being able to re-enter South Africa on another 90-day visa on an Australian passport. I plan to go to the UK in-between the two visas but need to know the necessary period in-between. I'd appreciate advice if anyone has had experience of this?

Comment: Like in many other countries, there is probably no hard and fast rule like the Schengen 90/180 rule, just that you shouldn’t attempt to live in SA through repeated or successive visits (as in the UK or US). The usual rule of thumb is then that you should stay out as much as you stayed in. But repeated long visits, even if spaced out quite a bit, will draw attention: what do you do during this time? How can you afford all this time without working? Are you not working in SA? Are you not attempting to live in SA? Etc.

Comment: That is also why the High Commission cannot tell you what the Immigration Officer will decide when you try to reenter.

Comment: You might also want to consider the potential tax residency implications of repeated lengthy stays in SA https://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-residency/South-Africa-Tax-Residency.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an official South African Immigration source. However, [Handyvisas.com](https://www.handyvisas.com/visa-policy/south-africa/) states:

> all citizens of countries who do not need a visa for South Africa are only able to spend a maximum of 90 days in the country within every year.

You could try contacting [South African Immigration Services](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/contact-us/84-service-queries/86-immigration-services) for clarification.

Comment: Could we contact the immigration services on behalf of OP and post an answer?

Comment: As usual with all these sites acting as intermediaries, the information is often incorrect or outdated, so I would take it with a pinch of salt. http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/immigration-services/exempt-countries says that for some countries (mostly in Africa), it’s indeed 90 days per year, but this is by far not the general case.

Comment: Thank you to those who took the time to comment on my query regarding South African entry visas. Most interesting!