# Can I go to Mauritius to get another 90 days in South Africa?

Tags: south-africa, 90-180-visa-rules, visa-runs, mauritius

Any 2024 updates on whether you can you go to Mauritius for a few days and get another 90 days on re-entry to South Africa, given that Mauritius is a SADAC country?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184254/can-i-leave-south-africa-for-a-week-and-then-come-back-for-another-three-months

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/can-i-leave-south-africa-before-my-90-days-expire-and-return-after-a-few-days-t

Comment: The existence of several questions on this topic that haven’t identified a hard and fast rule (such as the Schengen 90/180 limit or the US ‘travel outside of the contiguous territories and adjacent islands’) leads me to conclude one does not exist. Here’s another example, this time from an [Australian citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182679/australian-re-entering-south-africa-on-90-day-visa)

Comment: @Traveller the rule is in article 11(5) of the Immigration Act. Except for residents of neighbouring countries, or after a return to your home country, one should be readmitted for the remaining duration (if there is any left) or 7 days. There are also a number of countries for which the visa-free regime is limited to 90 days per year.